# What is the word that describes “the sound of a wood kindling”?

Tags: expressions, onomatopoeia

Each language has specific onomatopoeias.  I have not yet learned English words of that kind well.

In Japanese the sound of a wood kindling is described like ぼっ/bɔ/.
I’d like to know how the sound is described in English.

And if you know some way which is a better way to find onomatopoeias, would you tell me, please?

Comment: "a wood" = a forest.  So perhaps you mean "wood" (uncountable)

Comment: Is this the kind of sound you mean? https://freesound.org/people/CountryRoadFilms/sounds/449049/

Comment: I can't think of a word for the sound of wood starting to burn (kindling). You can say that a fire _crackles_, and the sound of flames springing up suddenly (for example, if the wood is soaked in paraffin) could be described as a _whoosh_.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about “a wood”!  Thank you, James.  I saw a sentence: “ The wood is damp and won’t kindle.”, and thought “the” is not appropriate and used “a” instead of “the”.  This kind of mistake makes me embarrassed because it happens when I am just not careful!

Comment: And I’m afraid  the sound I mean is not that shown in the link, thank you, James.

Comment: Thank you, Kite.  Phenomina of this kind are very interesting.  The sound I mean might not exist in English.   “Whoosh” may be nearer expression to me :)

Comment: How about this https://www.freesoundeffects.com/free-track/fireignite-426796/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Japanese is famous for onomatopoeia. It has a far wider range of both literal and psycho-acoustic onomatopoeia than English.

Wood, as it burns, may *crackle*, it can *pop*.

> Sound of [popping or crackling](https://freesound.org/people/CountryRoadFilms/sounds/449049/) wood, log, or kindling burning in a fire.

A fire might suddenly start with a ["whoosh"](https://www.epidemicsound.com/track/P4pkPUaMwe/) or perhaps ["whump"](https://www.freesoundeffects.com/free-track/fireignite-426796/) sound. The "whump" is heavier and closer to a small explosion.

Learn such words as part of your normal vocabulary.  But be aware that whereas in Japanese one may say "It did *gorogoro* down the hill", in English you'd probably just say "It rolled down the hill".

Comment: I regret not learning such words as you advise me to.  When I read PEANUTS or Diary of a Wimpy Kid, I tend to think about the content of conversations and ignore such words.  And I’m aware about the difference of the two languages , thank you.  I’m very happy to learn the words “crackle” and “ pop”.  Thank you very much for answering!

Comment: I've added some examples of whoosh and whump

Comment: James, thank you so much!  The /bɔ/ sound is “whump”! The “whoosh” sound I often hear in some games.  I can’t thank you too much!